# How to run encoder motor with motor driver and raspberry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, robotics

I am kinda new to the Robotics field and Raspberry Pi and has worked on very basic projects with the hardware so far. My current task is to run the "Encoder Motor" with a motor driver(preferably L293D).
I have already researched a lot on how to run the encoder motor with the raspberry pi but unable to find that.
If you can provide me with a detailed explanation on how to make connections and the code required that would really be helpful for me to understand from the robotics point of view and build projects on top of it.
Any relevant links/resources would be appreciable. Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean by "encoder motor"? .... motor and encoder are two separate electronic devices that are usually mechanically linked in some way, sort of like an LCD display and a touch panel, stuck together, but electrically separate .... google `raspberry pi motor driver` and `raspberry pi read encoder`

Comment: This question is too broad to currently fit here and makes a prohibited request for off-site resources. However, you also have two fundamental problems resulting from very unwise component choices.  First, you need to switch to an FET based driver which does not share the L293's notoriously absurd losses.  Next, as your task has a complex and multipart real-time requirement, you will find it orders of magnitude simpler to implement the control loop itself on a small MCU, which would accept only less time critical commands from the pi's multitasking operating system.

Comment: https://wiki.dfrobot.com/DC_Motor_Driver_HAT_SKU_DFR0592#target_5

Comment: @BruceAbbott Thanks for the link. Is there no way we can use the L293D motor Driver with raspberry pi to run the encoder motor? Also what if I don't use the Dfrobot library?
Your response would be appreciable. Thanks

Comment: L293D Motor Driver IC https://lastminuteengineers.com/l293d-dc-motor-arduino-tutorial/

Comment: Please don't use an L293D. They are horribly inefficient and can't really deliver the current they are rated for. The DFR0592 has an MCU that takes care of low level functions that the Pi may not be able to handle in real time. If you don't need that then just get a _good_ FET based motor driver shield. You don't have to use libraries either, but then you will have to fully understand driver board's operation and write all your own code. That's the way to go if you want to be a real expert. However this site is for specific questions only. If you need more then do what I do, Google it!